# Drawing boxes using request.security variables is not working correctly

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am drawing a box but it is not working as expected when I am fetching the built-in variables via request.security(). while passing the built-in variable of current chart working. can someone please help me what's wrong in the commented code ?

I am first finding a candle whose 14 length ATR value is greater than previous once found I am looking for another going back in time from right to left and if found 2nd candle as well and distance between both the candle is 6 or less I am drawing box with highest and lowest be the highest high and lowest low of the intermediate candles. No two adjacent candle should be considered as ATR Candles.

The below code contains methods with _XTF and without _XTF in the name. Methods without _XTF uses built-in variables which work fine but _XTF methods also uses built-in variable but fetched via request.security function which seems to be not working correctly can someone please help. you can try yourself by uncommenting it. Code starts from Project - Start

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=5
indicator("Project Work", overlay = true)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Common Variables - Start //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var box_array_support = array.new_box()
var box_array_resistence = array.new_box()

var violation_array = array.new_string(2, "")

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Common Variables - End ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Common Methods - Start ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Calculate Second ATR candle
isSecondATRCandle(index) =>
    
    // Calculate the range threshold for an ATR candle
    strongThreshold = ta.atr(14)[index]
    
    // Calculate the body candle for ATR
    candleRangeForATRCandleForATR = math.abs(high[index] - low[index])
    
    isSecondATRCandle = candleRangeForATRCandleForATR > strongThreshold 

    isSecondATRCandle

// Calculate Second ATR candle
isSecondATRCandle_XTF(index, Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time) =>

    // Calculate the range threshold for an ATR candle
    strongThreshold = Atr[index]
    
    // Calculate the body candle for ATR
    candleRangeForATRCandleForATR = math.abs(High[index] - Low[index])
    
    isSecondATRCandle = candleRangeForATRCandleForATR > strongThreshold

    isSecondATRCandle

// Calculate leg out candle
isFirstATRCandle(index) =>
    
    // Calculate the range threshold for an strong candle
    strongThreshold = ta.atr(14)[index]
    
    // Calculate the body candle for ATR
    candleRangeForATRCandleForATR = math.abs(high[index] - low[index])
    
    isFirstATRCandle = candleRangeForATRCandleForATR > strongThreshold

    isFirstATRCandle

// Calculate leg out candle
isFirstATRCandle_XTF(index, Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time) =>
    
    // Calculate the range threshold for an strong candle
    strongThreshold = Atr[index]
    
    // Calculate the body candle for ATR
    candleRangeForATRCandleForATR = math.abs(High[index] - Low[index])

    
    isFirstATRCandle = candleRangeForATRCandleForATR > strongThreshold

    isFirstATRCandle

// Function to count occurrences
countOccurrences(src, char) =>
    count = 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(src) - 1
        if array.get(src, i) == char
            count := count + 1
    count

//Find Support
find_Support() =>

    bool is_Support_Present = false
    bool is_Resistence_Present = false

    support = array.new_string()
    array.push(support, "S")

    for i= 2 to 8
        if not isSecondATRCandle(i)
            array.push(support, "B")
        else
            array.push(support, "S")
            break

    count = countOccurrences(support, "B")

    if count < 7
        is_Support_Present := true

    [distance_line, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type] = if is_Support_Present

        distance_line = 0.0
        near_by_line = 0.0
        number_of_base = count
        support_type = "Support"
        second_atr_candle = bar_index - count - 2
        first_atr_candle = bar_index + 1

        for j = 2 to count + 1
            near_by_line := near_by_line == 0.0 ? high[j] : near_by_line < high[j] ? high[j] : near_by_line
            distance_line := distance_line == 0.0 ? low[j] : distance_line < low[j] ? distance_line : low[j]

        [distance_line, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type]

    [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type]
    
//Find Support
find_Support_XTF(Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time) =>

    bool is_Support_Present = false
    bool is_Resistence_Present = false

    support = array.new_string()
    array.push(support, "S")

    for i= 2 to 8
        if not isSecondATRCandle_XTF(i, Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time)
            array.push(support, "B")
        else
            array.push(support, "S")
            break

    count = countOccurrences(support, "B")

    if count < 7
        is_Support_Present := true

    [distance_line, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type] = if is_Support_Present

        distance_line = 0.0
        near_by_line = 0.0
        number_of_base = count
        support_type = "Support"
        second_atr_candle = bar_index - count - 2
        first_atr_candle = bar_index + 1

        for j = 2 to count + 1
            near_by_line := near_by_line == 0.0 ? High[j] : near_by_line < High[j] ? High[j] : near_by_line
            distance_line := distance_line == 0.0 ? Low[j] : distance_line < Low[j] ? distance_line : Low[j]

        [distance_line, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type]

    [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type]


//Find Resistence
find_Resistence() =>

    bool is_Resistence_Present = false
    bool is_Support_Present = false

    resistence = array.new_string()
    array.push(resistence, "R")

    for i= 2 to 8
        if not isSecondATRCandle(i)
            array.push(resistence, "B")
        else
            array.push(resistence, "R")
            break

    count = countOccurrences(resistence, "B")
    
    if count < 7
        is_Resistence_Present := true
    
    [distance_line, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type] = if is_Resistence_Present

        distance_line = 0.0
        near_by_line = 0.0
        number_of_base = count
        support_type = "Resistence"
        second_atr_candle = bar_index - count - 2
        first_atr_candle = bar_index + 1

        for j = 2 to count + 1
            near_by_line := near_by_line == 0.0 ? low[j] : near_by_line > low[j] ? low[j] : near_by_line
            distance_line := distance_line == 0.0 ? high[j] : distance_line < high[j] ? high[j] : distance_line

        [distance_line, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type]
                
    [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type]

find_Resistence_XTF(Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time) =>

    bool is_Resistence_Present = false
    bool is_Support_Present = false

    resistence = array.new_string()
    array.push(resistence, "R")

    for i= 2 to 8
        if not isSecondATRCandle_XTF(i, Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time)
            array.push(resistence, "B")
        else
            array.push(resistence, "R")
            break

    count = countOccurrences(resistence, "B")
    
    if count < 7
        is_Resistence_Present := true
    
    [distance_line, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, near_by_line, number_of_base,  support_type] = if is_Resistence_Present

        distance_line = 0.0
        near_by_line = 0.0
        number_of_base = count
        support_type = "Resistence"
        second_atr_candle = bar_index - count - 2
        first_atr_candle = Bar_Index + 1

        for j = 2 to count + 1
            near_by_line := near_by_line == 0.0 ? Low[j] : near_by_line > Low[j] ? Low[j] : near_by_line
            distance_line := distance_line == 0.0 ? High[j] : distance_line < High[j] ? High[j] : distance_line

        [distance_line, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type]
                
    [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_type]

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Common Methods - End //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Project - Start ////////////////////////////////////////////////////



///////////////////////////////////// ------------------------> This is Working - Start <------------------------//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status] = if isFirstATRCandle(1)
    if open < close
        [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status] = find_Support()

        [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status]
    else
        [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status] = find_Resistence()
        
        [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status]
///////////////////////////////////// ------------------------> This is Working - End <------------------------//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



///////////////////////////////////// ------------------------> This is Not Working - Start Please Uncomment Below <------------------------//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "75", [open, high, low, close, ta.atr(14), bar_index, time])

//[is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status] = if isFirstATRCandle_XTF(1, Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time)
//    if Open < Close
//        [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status] = find_Support(Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time)

//        [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status]
//    else
//        [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status] = find_Resistence(Open, High, Low, Close, Atr, Bar_Index, Time)
        
//        [is_Support_Present, is_Resistence_Present, second_atr_candle, first_atr_candle, distance_line, near_by_line, number_of_base, support_status]

///////////////////////////////////// ------------------------> This is Not Working - End <------------------------//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





        // Plot Box
if is_Support_Present
    id_Support = box.new(left=second_atr_candle, top=near_by_line,right=first_atr_candle, bottom=distance_line, extend =  extend.right, bgcolor = color.new(color = color.green, transp = 80), border_color = color.green)
    array.push(box_array_support, id_Support)


// Plot Box
if is_Resistence_Present
    id_Resistence = box.new(left=second_atr_candle, top=near_by_line,right=first_atr_candle, bottom=distance_line, extend =  extend.right, bgcolor = color.new(color = color.red, transp = 80), border_color = color.red)
    array.push(box_array_resistence, id_Resistence)

if array.size(box_array_support) > 0

    for k=array.size(box_array_support)-1 to 0
        each_box = array.get(box_array_support,k)
        if Low < each_box.get_top() and Low > each_box.get_bottom()
            each_box.set_bgcolor(color.new(color = color.blue, transp = 85))
            each_box.set_border_color(color.blue)
        if Low < each_box.get_bottom()
            box.delete(each_box)
            array.remove(box_array_support, k)
            array.pop(violation_array)
            array.unshift(violation_array, "Support")
            

if array.size(box_array_resistence) > 0

    for l=array.size(box_array_resistence)-1 to 0
        each_box = array.get(box_array_resistence,l)
        if High < each_box.get_top() and high > each_box.get_bottom()
            each_box.set_bgcolor(color.new(color = color.purple, transp = 85))
            each_box.set_border_color(color.purple)
        if High > each_box.get_top()
            box.delete(each_box)
            array.remove(box_array_resistence, l)
            array.pop(violation_array)
            array.unshift(violation_array, "Resistence")


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Project - End //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Plot ATR Candles - Start /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Set the color for the bullish and bearish candles
ATRColor = color.blue
bearishColor = color.rgb(242,54,69)
bullishColor = color.rgb(8,153,129)

normalCondition = open < close

// Use the barcolor() function to change the candle color based on the condition
barcolor(isFirstATRCandle(0) ? ATRColor : normalCondition ? bullishColor : bearishColor)


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Plot ATR Candles - End ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```